# passing specific radion buttons to a function

Tags: javascript

I've got a function that applies to all radio buttons on a page, I can't seem to specify it to run only for specific ones.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
 $(function() {
     var $divs = $('#divs > div');
      $divs.first().show()
      $('input[type=radio]').on('change',function() {
              $divs.hide();
              $divs.eq( $('input[type=radio]').index( this ) ).show();
       });
});
});//]]>
```

Comment: you need to show the relevant html

Comment: <input id="id_radio1" type="radio" name="name_radio" value="value_radio1" checked="checked"/>

Comment: No, you need to add the structure we need with `div`, `input`, etc. that your javascript expects to see.  And the code should be edited into your question, not posted as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Give each radio button a unique id and then just select the ones you want:

```
$('#id_radio1, #id_radio4, #id_radio9').on('change', function() {...
```